# Matching two columns

Tags: excel

I have two Columns "Person Number" and "Company Code", Person Numbers can correspond to multiple company codes and vice versa .

What I need to do is match Person Number with each Comapany Code it is associated with and list the person number and this codes e.g

In the photo the way the information is now is to the left and the way I need it to be is on the right.

Does anyone have any ideas how to go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: could you show a clearer example of what you have and what you want as a result?

Comment: Sorry Please see the original post I've added a picture

Comment: My Input data is part of a larger collection so I can't preprocess it unfortunately. The output can be in any order as long as each Person Number only occurs once

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pivot table for this.  Simply select the data and then create a pivot table (you didn't specifiy the version of Excel, so I can't be more specific.)